# What is the command to enchant a weapon multiple levels?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use a command to enchant a weapon multiple levels in a Minecraft server. How can I do this?

Comment: -1 The Minecraft End User Licence Agreement (EULA for short) clearly states that it is not allowed to donator perks in terms of "pay to win gear",

Comment: @Ferrybig many servers offer extra kits as gifts to the player who donated. Basically they're complimentary

Comment: @Ferrybig proof?

Comment: @JimJones https://account.mojang.com/terms#commercial "ask for donations (as opposed to direct charges) IF you do not offer the individual donor something in exchange that only he or she can use. You may offer server wide rewards if donation goals are achieved though."

Comment: Honestly, why does this question have so many downvotes? It's a good question

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple:

`/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:32,lvl:5},{id:34,lvl:5},{id:33,lvl:1}]}`

This gives you a diamond pick with Unbreaking 5, Efficiency 5, Silk Touch 1
[Here](http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/minecraft-enchantment-ids/) are more enchantment IDs you can use.

If you're using Essentials you can use `/enchant <id> <lvl>` (e.g. `/enchant 33 1` for Silk Touch 1) for example to enchant the item you're currently holding. This way you can upgrade existing items without book/anvil or even overwrite or remove existing enchantments.

PS: Mojang changed their policy regarding pay to play. It is no longer completely forbidden. See [here](https://account.mojang.com/terms#commercial) for more info. Pay to win is still forbidden, though.